# When does a v-for loop re-render?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a `v-for` loop which has a method in it named `count`:

```
<div class="checkbox" v-for="(index, value) in range">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" :value="Number(value)" v-model="values">

        <span class="hotels">{{ count(Number(value)) }}</span>
    </label>
</div><!-- /.checkbox -->
```

On render it obviously fires the `count` method. Also whenever I click a checkbox it will re-render and fire the `count` method.

Except whenever I have another component I want the count to run again for all of these components. I want them all to update.

I had this working previously but after my re-factor it no longer seems to work.

Does this method also have the ability to re-fire whenever a dependency has changed inside of it like a computed property?

This is the code before my re-factor:

https://gist.github.com/stephan-v/58cd37042b3c20ff4af0e21e0fbdf92e

I had 2 of these components and the count used to update whenever I updated my vuex store.

**Edit**

Is it possible for a single property in your template tag to be reactive and re-render the complete template therefore causing methods like `count` to run again?

Comment: you have your `index, value` pair flipped in the `v-for`. It should be `value, index`. You should also have a `:key` value.

Comment: That does not solve anything but thanks.

Comment: 1. You can use: `v-model.number` instead of calling `Number(value)` .  
2. You can try listening to @change event on input and call [forceUpdate](http://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-forceUpdate)

Comment: @MatWaligora where is the documentation for @change? Can't seem to find it. Won't the forceUpdate and re-render the current component? The other component won't know anything about this.

Comment: @Stephan-v I don't think it is in the docs. You can have `<input v-model="values" @change="yourMethod">` and then call `this.$forceUpdate()` in `yourMethod`.